# Comparison of Files in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing, compare, string-comparison, file-comparison

We have the following code:

```
If Not File.Exists(trancheDataPath & sDealName & ".txt") OrElse (trancheInsert <> File.ReadAllText(trancheDataPath & sDealName & ".txt")) Then
            File.WriteAllText(trancheDataPath & sDealName & ".txt", trancheInsert)
        End If
```

We have a string of data that we want to compare with the content in the file and see if there is any change/difference in the new data. Currently, I am using the following method to do this:

```
trancheInsert <> File.ReadAllText("E:\Stored.txt")
```

where trancheInsert is of string type and contains the new data.

Similar to above code mentioned, there are similar pieces of code to write to 15 files in a function being called parallely, which occupies a lot of memory.

So,is there a better,faster and memory-efficient way than the above method being used to compare the data?

Comment: You should calculate a hash of each of the two text values - probably MD5 - and then compare the two results. That's how many download sites enable you to validate a file after downloading it. There is plenty of information around on the subject of calculating hashes.

Comment: A checksum will [probably be slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358510/how-to-compare-2-files-fast-using-net) than a byte by byte comparison

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28834817/14171304