# Comparing string outputs between Azure Properties.ContentMD5 and Get-Filehash

Tags: powershell, encoding, hash, md5, azure-blob-storage

How do I compare the output of `Get-FileHash` directly with the output of `Properties.ContentMD5`?

---

I'm putting together a PowerShell script that takes some local files from my system and copies them to an Azure Blob Storage Container.

The files change daily so I have added in a check to see if the file already exists in the container before uploading it.

I use `Get-FileHash` to read the local file:

```bsh
$LocalFileHash = (Get-FileHash "D:\file.zip" -Algorithm MD5).Hash
```

Which results in `$LocalFileHash` holding this: `67BF2B6A3E6657054B4B86E137A12382`

I use this code to get the checksum of the blob file already transferred to the container:

```bsh
$BlobFile = "Path\To\file.zip"
$AZContext = New-AZStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -SASToken "<token here>"

$RemoteBlobFile = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $AZContext -Blob $BlobFile -ErrorAction Ignore 
if ($ExistingBlobFile) { 
    $cloudblob = [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob]$RemoteBlobFile.ICloudBlob
    $RemoteBlobHash = $cloudblob.Properties.ContentMD5
}
```

This value of `$RemoteBlobHash` is set to `Z78raj5mVwVLS4bhN6Ejgg==`

No problem, I thought, I'll just decrypt the Base64 string and compare:

```bsh
$output = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($RemoteBlobHash))
```

Which gives me `g�+j>fWKK��7�#�` so not directly comparable ☹

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31183477) shows someone in a similar pickle but I don't think they were using `Get-FileHash` given the format of their local MD5 result.

Other things I've tried:

- changing the System.Text.Encoding line above `UTF8` to UTF16 & ASCII which changes the output but not to anything recognisable.
- dabbling with GetBytes to see if that helped:

```bsh
$output = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF16.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($RemoteBlobHash)))
```

Note: Using md5sum to compare the local file and a downloaded copy of file.zip results in the same MD5 string as `Get-FileHash`: 67BF2B6A3E6657054B4B86E137A12382

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContentMD5` is a base64 representation of the *binary* hash value, not the resulting hex string :)

```
$md5sum = [convert]::FromBase64String('Z78raj5mVwVLS4bhN6Ejgg==')
$hdhash = [BitConverter]::ToString($md5sum).Replace('-','')
```

Here we convert base64 -> binary -> hexadecimal

---

If you need to do it the other way around (ie. for obtaining a local file hash, then using that to search for blobs in Azure), you'll first need to split the hexadecimal string into byte-size chunks, then convert the resulting byte array to base64:

```
$hdhash = '67BF2B6A3E6657054B4B86E137A12382'
$bytes  = [byte[]]::new($hdhash.Length / 2)
for($i = 0; $i -lt $bytes.Length; $i++){
  $offset = $i * 2
  $bytes[$i] = [convert]::ToByte($hdhash.Substring($offset,2), 16)
}
$md5sum = [convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

Comment: Thankyou! This works perfectly! The binary aspect was definitely something that was tripping me up. The Microsoft page for the [ContentMD5 property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobproperties.contentmd5?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) is rather sparse which didn't help 

Comment: The length of the base64 string gave it away - not nearly long enough to encode the full hex string representation (32 chars), but long enough to encode the hash itself (16 bytes)