# MD5 hash of blob uploaded on Azure does not match with same file on local machine

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am currently working on uploading a .json file on Azure Blob storage. All is working fine except when i try to macth the MD5 hash of uploaded file with the local file (exactly same one which was uploaded). Local file returns a byte array where are blob.Properties.ContentMD5 returns a string and both do not match.

Local MD5 hash: 67a45ac2700d14cc867c897182fde402 (is in hex)

blob.Properties.ContentMD5: c9QoHkamgiKTRANifltOGQ==

Any possible way to match both these?

Comment: Hello @Bogdan Buricea, If the answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. If you have any other concerns, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Blob ContentMD5 is Base64 String, they are different type and can not math directly.

Please convert MD5 byte array into Base64 string and see if that matches.

Ref: [MD5 hash of blob uploaded on Azure doesnt match with same file on local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183477/md5-hash-of-blob-uploaded-on-azure-doesnt-match-with-same-file-on-local-machine)