# Hash a file as its being recived

Tags: c#, hash

End goal:
Users are uploading a large number of files in different sizes to my web site. And i dont want duplicate files on the disk.

The solution i have been using is a simple SH1 hash of the file when it is uploaded. With code like this:

```
public static string HashFile(string FileName)
{
   using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(FileName))
   {
      SHA1Managed sha = new SHA1Managed();
      byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);

      string sendCheckSum = BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-",string.Empty);
                    return sendCheckSum;
   } 
}
```

This "works" fine for smaller files, but its a big pain when the file is 30gb. So i would like to hash the file as im reciving it from the client. I get the file from the client in "chunks" and size of the chunk is not always static.

Code that recives the file.

```
int chunk = context.Request["chunk"] != null ? int.Parse(context.Request["chunk"]) : 0;
int chunks = context.Request["chunks"] != null ? int.Parse(context.Request["chunks"]) : 0;
string fileName = context.Request["name"] != null ? context.Request["name"] : string.Empty;

HttpPostedFile fileUpload = context.Request.Files[0];    
string fullFilePath = Path.Combine(SiteSettings.UploadTempFolder, fileName);
using (var fs = new FileStream(fullFilePath, chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
{
    var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
    fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    **// Here i want the hash, when i have the file data in memory.**
}
```

Comment: Do you mean [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) ? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3621316/1997232), SHA-1 also has such methods.

Comment: That seems to be the best way @Sinatr , post it as a reply :)

Comment: Have you made it working? Then post the answer yourself for future visitors.

Comment: Yea i will figured you wanted the presius internet points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a cut and paste from:

[Compute a hash from a stream of unknown length in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621283/compute-a-hash-from-a-stream-of-unknown-length-in-c-sharp/3621316#3621316)

MD5, like other hash functions, does not require two passes.

To start:

```
HashAlgorithm hasher = ..;
hasher.Initialize();
```

As each block of data arrives:

```
byte[] buffer = ..;
int bytesReceived = ..;
hasher.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, bytesReceived, null, 0);
```

To finish and retrieve the hash:

```
hasher.TransformFinalBlock(new byte[0], 0, 0);
byte[] hash = hasher.Hash;
```

This pattern works for any type derived from `HashAlgorithm`, including `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` and `SHA1Managed`.

`HashAlgorithm` also defines a method `ComputeHash` which takes a `Stream` object; however, this method will block the thread until the stream is consumed. Using the `TransformBlock` approach allows an "asynchronous hash" that is computed as data arrives without using up a thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can always create your own stream :)

```
public class ActionStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _innerStream;
    private readonly Action<byte[], int, int> _readAction;

    public ActionStream(Stream innerStream, Action<byte[], int, int> readAction)
    {
        _innerStream = innerStream;
        _readAction = readAction;
    }

    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanSeek => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override long Length => _innerStream.Length;
    public override long Position
    {
        get { return _innerStream.Position; }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    public override void Flush() { }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var bytesRead = _innerStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        _readAction(buffer, offset, bytesRead);

        return bytesRead;
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _innerStream.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) 
    { 
      throw new NotSupportedException(); 
    }
}
```

This allows you to bind together the two stream operations you're doing:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
{
  var as = new ActionStream(fileUpload.InputStream,
    (buffer, offset, bytesRead) =>
    {
      fs.Write(buffer, offset, bytesRead);
    });

  var sha = new SHA1Managed();
  var checksum = sha.ComputeHash(as);
}
```

This assumes that `SHA1Manager` reads through every single byte of the input stream in order - you should check that. I'm pretty sure that is how it works, though :)

Comment: Overriden Flush() should call base.Flush();

Comment: @ipavlu `Stream.Flush` is abstract, so nope. At best, it could throw. But the question is moot anyway, since we don't support writing.